# Custom Spartacus site

Tags: spartacus-storefront

i had created new wcms custom site along with content and product catalogs by creating similar extension as electronicstore, my extension name is dastore. for this site i want to create new spartacus site similar to electronics-spa.
in spartacussampledataaddon, i had followed impex files of electronics store and created all the necessary folders and files. Modified SpaSampleAddOnSampleDataImportService.java to consider my custom site also for import.
after build and startup, ran an update by selecting "dastore" and "spartacussampledataaddon".
But still my impex files were not considered for execution.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to run update including dastore, spartacussampledataaddon, addonsupport(if you have impex on any of your addon, you need to include this, then your addon impex will be part of sample data and core data events)